# How to show the count down in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Trying to create a count down demo, using angular js.

Once am in idle state for 30 seconds, i need to show the count down starting from 10 to 0,

How to implement the count down timer.

this is what I have tried.

```
var time = $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('shutdwon');
                setTimeout( function () {
                    $location.path('/');
                }, 1500);
        }, 30000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple try this out

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b3wLsfz5/2/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="countController">Count starts after 30 seconds<div>Count :: {{countDown}}</div>
<div>
```

**script**

```
function countController($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.countDown = 10;
    var time = $timeout(function () {
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if ($scope.countDown > 0) {
                $scope.countDown--;
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer)
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 1500);
    }, 30000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done this kind of thing to show the session time out information.

Check the following sample code. Which can be improved and used according to your requirements.

```
function MyCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
       $scope.isUserActive = false;
        $scope.userActivityInterval = 1000;
        $scope.redirectLoginInterval =10000;
        $scope.timerSpan=  $scope.redirectLoginInterval/  $scope.userActivityInterval;
      $scope.resetActivity=function () {
            if ($scope.isUserActive == true) {


                clearTimeout($scope.redirectTimer);
                $scope.redirectTimer = $timeout( $scope.redirectToLogin, $scope.redirectLoginInterval);

                $scope.timerSpan = $scope.redirectLoginInterval/  $scope.userActivityInterval;
            }
            else {
                $scope.timerSpan -= $scope.userActivityInterval / $scope.userActivityInterval;
            }

            clearTimeout($scope.activityTimer);
            $scope.activityTimer = $timeout($scope.resetActivity, $scope.userActivityInterval);

            $scope.isUserActive = false;
        };   

  $scope.activityTimer = $timeout($scope.resetActivity, $scope.userActivityInterval);
        $scope.redirectTimer = $timeout($scope.resetActivity, $scope.redirectLoginInterval);
```

}

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Nj3/21/)